# How to lower costs of having MySQL db in Google Cloud

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I set up Google Cloud MySQL, I store there just one user (email, password, address) and I'm querying it quite often due to testing purposes of my website. I set up minimal zone availability, the lowest SSD storage, memory 3.75GB, 1vCPUs, automatic backups disabled but running that database from the last 6 days costing me £15... How can I decrease the costs of having MySQL database in the cloud? I'm pretty sure paying that amount is way too much. Where is my mistake?

Comment: Can you use a Secret Manager for credentials? Or a Firestore database at least? do you really need a MySQL database for that?

Comment: I need cloud storage as I will be building dashboard for users where I will need to store their results (HL7 files) somewhere ,and be able to access them depending on the user.

Comment: Cloud storage and cloud database are completely different services. 
Even if you meant a database, a Firestore might be a much better choice. 
In any case you are not going to store emails and passwords decrypted, are you?

Comment: You can use micro VM, to use less CPU and memory

Comment: @snaky If [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71578079/13171940) or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest using the [Google Pricing Calculator](https://cloud.google.com/products/calculator) to check the different configurations and pricing you could have for a MySQL database in Cloud SQL.

#### Choosing Instance type

As you've said in your question, you're currently using the lowest standard instance, which is based on [CPU and memory pricing](https://cloud.google.com/sql/pricing#cpu-mem-pricing).

As you're currently using your database for testing purposes, I could suggest to configure your database with the lowest *Shared-Core Machine Type* which is **`db-f1-micro`**, as shown [here](https://cloud.google.com/sql/pricing#instance-pricing). But [note](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/instance-settings#machine-type-2ndgen) that

> The `db-f1-micro` and `db-g1-small` machine types are not included in the Cloud SQL SLA. These machine types are designed to provide low-cost test and development instances only. Do not use them for production instances.

#### Choosing Storage type

As you have selected the lowest allowed disk space, you could lower cost changing the storage type to HDD instead of a SSD if you haven't done so, as stated in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/instance-settings#storage-type-2ndgen):

> Choosing  **SSD**, the default value, provides your instance with SSD storage. SSDs provide lower latency and higher data throughput. If you do not need high-performance access to your data, for example for long-term storage or rarely accessed data, you can reduce your costs by choosing  **HDD**.

- Note that Storage type could only be selected when you're creating the instance and could not be changed later, as stated in the message when creating your instance.

  > Choice is permanent. Storage type affects performance.

[image: Storage type]

#### Stop instance when is not in use

Finally, you could lower costs by stopping the database instance when it is not in use as pointed in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/start-stop-restart-instance?hl=en#stop).

> Stopping an instance suspends instance charges. The instance data is unaffected, and charges for storage and IP addresses continue to apply.

---

#### Using Google Pricing Calculator

The following information is presented as a calculation exercise based in the [Google Pricing Calculator](https://cloud.google.com/products/calculator)

> The estimated fees provided by Google Cloud Pricing Calculator are for discussion purposes only and are not binding on either you or Google. Your actual fees may be higher or lower than the estimate. A more detailed and specific list of fees will be provided at time of sign up

Following the suggestions above, you could get a monthly estimate of 6.41 GBP. Based on a 24 hour per 7 days running instance.

[image: MySQL instance on Cloud SQL HDD 24x7]

And using a SSD, it increases to 7.01 GBP. As said before, the only way to change the storage type would be to create a new instance and load your data.

[image: MySQL instance on Cloud SQL SDD 24x7]

And this could lower to 2.04 GBP if you only run it for 8 hours 5 days a week running on HDD.

[image: MySQL instance on Cloud SQL HDD 8x5]

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are running your Instance for 24*7. You can schedule, to start or stop the instance when not required. If you can reduce the Instances running hours, the cost will be reduced. To schedule on and off automatically you can through this Google cloud blog https://cloud.google.com/blog/topics/developers-practitioners/lower-development-costs-schedule-cloud-sql-instances-start-and-stop.
Click on the Images link for
Cost comparison:
Instance running 10hrs/day Vs 24hrs/day.
[24hrs/day]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8tjA1.png
[10hrs/day]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/APIjd.png

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34872949)